# Case when in jpa @query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, jpql

I hope I can explain myself enough.
I'm working with JPA @Query. I need to do a Case-When.
If the id is from a certain company, return all employees, otherwise return only employees from that company

In PostgreSQL is working the query

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW_EMPLOYEE v 
WHERE (v.name LIKE '%%' OR v.lastname LIKE '%%' OR v.sso LIKE '%%')
    AND (CASE WHEN (SELECT c.acronym FROM company c WHERE id = 1) <> 'TH' THEN v.company_id = 1 ELSE TRUE END)
```

But when I code it in JPA @Query

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM ViewEmployee u WHERE (u.name LIKE %?1% OR u.lastname LIKE %?1% OR u.sso LIKE %?1%) " +
               "AND (CASE WHEN (SELECT c.acronym FROM Company c WHERE c.id = ?2) <> 'TH' THEN u.viewEmployeeId.companyId = ?2 ELSE TRUE END)")
   fun findEmployee(search: String, companyId: Long, pageable: Pageable): Page<ViewEmployee>
```

Give me this error message

```
unexpected token: = near line 1, column 251 [SELECT u FROM com.solucioneskuali.models.ViewEmployee u WHERE (u.name LIKE ?1 OR u.lastname LIKE ?1 OR u.sso LIKE ?1) AND (CASE WHEN (SELECT c.acronym FROM com.solucioneskuali.models.Company c WHERE c.id = ?2) <> 'TH' THEN u.viewEmployeeId.companyId = ?2 ELSE TRUE END)]
```

Can someone help to find what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The unexpected token is the `?` before each numbered parameter.

Comment: it is for the parameters on the function. you need to put it in the query to say which parameter to use

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with JPA @Query but at a glance, `LIKE %?1%` seems wrong to me.  If this kind of parametrisation works like macro substitution, then I'd expect the pattern expression to be enclosed in quotation marks, like this: `LIKE '%?1%'`.  However, if this is proper parametrisation, where the parameter type is either specified or automatically determined from the value, then I'm guessing the expression should look something like this: `LIKE '%' || ?1 || '%'`.  Again, I'm not familiar with the software so those are just my guesses, but that's where I would start investigating.

Comment: @AndriyM `LIKE %?1%` is how works in JPA using @Query.  Here's some documentation in case you're interested. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-like-queries#query

Comment: I looked closer at the error message and it seems to me that the token at the position specified in the message (line 1, column 251) is the `=` in the `THEN` clause of the CASE expression (`THEN u.viewEmployeeId.companyId = ?2`).  If you checked the query in Postgres and it worked, then my only guess at this point is that JPA @Query's own SQL parser doesn't like a `=` in that context, even though the underlying database engine is fine with that syntax.  Therefore I would try and rewrite the logic expressed by the CASE expression differently so as to avoid dealing with boolean values like that.

Comment: And thanks for the link, by the way, I can see now that the `LIKE %?1%` should be fine.  To me that looks like evidence that JPA @Query may indeed have its own parser of SQL syntax, which may accept most of what is acceptable in regular SQL but at the same time not support some conventions of some SQL products (like a boolean expression in a context where usually only a non-boolean expression would be expected).

Comment: @AndriyM I solve it making 2 functions for each case. It's not the best way, but it was taking me much time. Thanks for the help anyway.